# Morphia filtering wrong

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

I am using the following code to filter restaurants with a grade more than 80 but less than 100

```
List<Restaurant_M> r = ds.find(Restaurant_M.class)
                             .field("grades.score").lessThan(100)
                             .field("grades.score").greaterThan(80)
                             .asList();
```

It is working but I am getting 1 extra document which is shown below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572eb5df1d739cc73c21fab1"),
    "address" : {
            "building" : "65",
            "coord" : [
                    -73.9782725,
                    40.7624022
            ],
            "street" : "West   54 Street",
            "zipcode" : "10019"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-08-22T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "C",
                    "score" : 131
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-09-25T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-08T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "B",
                    "score" : 25
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2012-10-15T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 11
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2011-10-19T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade" : "A",
                    "score" : 13
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Murals On 54/Randolphs'S",
    "restaurant_id" : "40372466"
}
```

this does not have a score in the 80-100 range. this beats me. can anyone tell why this document is being returned?

EDIT:
So i tried doing this with the JAVA driver and surprisingly i get exactly the same results. the code is as follows

```
FindIterable<Document> r = collection.find(
            Filters.and(Filters.gt("grades.score", 80),     Filters.lt("grades.score", 100))
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, after all the head-banging i did for the past week, i was unable to do this with morphia so i resorted to the java driver and the below gives the correct results

```
Bson f1 = Filters.gt("score", 80);
Bson f2 = Filters.lt("score", 100);
Bson f3 = and (f1, f2);

MongoCursor<Document> c = collection.find(
            elemMatch("grades", f3))
                                    .iterator();
```